# How to write batch script for installation of atg in linux?

Tags: java, linux, batch-file, atg

How to write script for skipping the "next" buttons, include path for files in batch file? Is there any way to do it other than using **AUTOIT** or similar tools, which registers key strokes while installing?

Comment: You can use AutoHotkey, Google it for more information and tutorials on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Tools aren't needed. Run the following commands:

exefilename /r  *for recording*, which generates a properties file(default path is same as your .exe file)

To trigger a silent installer from the command line, type the following command:

exefilename -i silent

A properties file may also be specified from the command line:

exefilename -f

source:http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=Q000448&sliceId=

Comment: For linux on ACC 11 .bin it is: -r <path_to_generate_response_file> to generate the file and -f <path_to_installer_properties_file> to use it - but not working on CentOS 6.5.   Also, looking for cim.sh automation, not just ATG*.bin files.

Comment: "./OCACC11.0_354REL.bin -i silent < OCACC11.0_354REL.properties" or "./OCACC11.0_354REL.bin -i silent" does work.  But did not without the silent flag ..., not sure why.